# What can cause color loss in a finished beer?

Tags: aging, color

I made an American Brown ale that turned out very dark brown. 
I opened the last couple of bottles a month or so apart after most of the batch.
The color seems to have faded to a significantly lighter shade of brown, 
still in the brown ale normal range but different enough from the fresh beer to confuse me.
What can possibly cause this phenomenon?

RECIPE:
Based on:
https://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/view/784491/brown-ale-chance-dodds

Title: Brown Ale

Brew Method: BIAB 
Style Name: American Brown Ale 
Boil Time: 60 min 
Batch Size: 11 liters (fermentor volume)
Boil Size: 17 liters
Boil Gravity: 1.031
Efficiency: 60% (brew house)
No Chill: 20 minute extended hop boil time

STATS:
Original Gravity: 1.049
Final Gravity: 1.010
ABV (standard): 5.12%
IBU (tinseth): 32.19
SRM (morey): 19.59
Mash pH: 0

FERMENTABLES:
2.5 kg - Pilsner (87.7%)
200 g - CaraMunich II (7%)
100 g - De-Husked Caraf II (3.5%)
50 g - Melanoidin (1.8%)

HOPS:
5 g - Magnum, Type: Pellet, AA: 15, Use: Boil for 40 min, IBU: 20.44
5 g - Ekuanot, Type: Pellet, AA: 14.25, Use: Boil for 0 min, IBU: 11.76
25 g - Ekuanot, Type: Pellet, AA: 14.25, Use: Dry Hop for 5 days

MASH GUIDELINES:
1) Infusion, Temp: 68 C, Time: 45 min, Amount: 17 L

OTHER INGREDIENTS:
1 tsp - Irish moss, Time: 10 min, Type: Water Agt, Use: Boil

YEAST:
Fermentis / Safale - American Ale Yeast US-05
Starter: No
Form: Dry
Fermentation Temp: 18 C
Pitch Rate: 0.75 (M cells / ml / deg P)

PRIMING:
CO2 Level: 2.52 Volumes

Generated by Brewer's Friend - https://www.brewersfriend.com/
Date: 2019-12-18 10:39 UTC 
Recipe Last Updated: 2019-09-30 16:12 UTC

Comment: Did you use any kind of brown sugar? Normal caramel is not colorproof in beer. Maybe post your recipe in the question.

Comment: Didn't use any kind of sugar in the recipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been brewing for 10+ years so the answer I give will be based upon experience. I have often seen beer to lighten in colour to some extent and have generally attributed this to the settling of sediments and proteins from the beer during the conditioning phase. With less sediment in suspension, light can more easily pass through the liquid, making it appear lighter in colour.

Comment: I would add to this that beer, seen in a fermenter or a bucket, also looks darker or less transparent than when poured in a glass.